# Should Kotlin standard functions (run, let, also, apply) be used to unwrap optionals, or should there be a separate method for this?

Tags: android, kotlin, option-type, conventions

So I was reading about the standard functions `run, let, also, apply`, as I saw them being used in different cases throughout my codebase, and discovered two things:

All four of these methods unwrap optionals, but they also have different return types as well as different contexts, so to say.

Reading into [Kotlin's Null-Safety documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), it appears the recommended way to unwrap optionals in Kotlin would be to use `let`.

A little bit of background regarding these four methods:

```
val string = ""
val thing: String = string.apply { length } + string.also { it.length }
val other: Int = string.run { length } + string.let { it.length }
```

This code would compile, due to the return types of the four methods. For more information on this methods, you could take a look at [this blog post](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84)

However, as all four of these methods unwrap optionals, some developers in my team would prefer writing:

```
textView?.run {
someLongMethod(
        text = text,
        blah = blah,
        blah2 = blah2
    )
}
```

over

```
textView?.let {
someLongMethod{
        text = it.text,
        blah = it.blah,
        blah2 = it.blah2
    )
}
```

The aforementioned preference is stylistically sensible, and also consistent, as in both cases, we are not leveraging the return type of the either `let` nor `run` blocks. Furthermore, using `run` unwraps the optional `textView`, also removing the redundant `it.` from needing to be written over and over again in my method call.

The entire premise of my argument is based on the fact that it is acceptable, stylistically and conventionally, to do the above.

If so, in this particular context, replacing `let` with `also` or `run` with `apply` will result in no change, neither inside their respective blocks, nor will it have any side effects.

Therefore, I feel that using any one of these four methods to unwrap optionals allows for wild inconsistencies amongst developers within teams, and there is no argument to warrant the use one over the other in this case, except for personal choice.

---

I have therefore proposed the following two extensions (although the second one could use a nicer name):

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <T, R> T.unwrap(block: (T) -> R) {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    block(this)
}

@UseExperimental(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <T, R> T.unwrapInScope(block: T.() -> R) {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    block()
}
```

So that the block of code written earlier becomes:

```
textView?.unwrapInScope {
someLongMethod(
        text = text,
        blah = blah,
        blah2 = blah2
    )
}
```

And since we're not leveraging the return type, it would then be preferred to use the extension in this case. The other `unwrap` extension would then be used for when `let` would have been preferred over `run`.

This is of course only my argument. However, I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing? Should we not be using `run` to unwrap optionals, to begin with? Or should `Kotlin` have built in different methods to clear up this discrepancy?

Comment: They're not optionals, and you're not unwrapping anything. They're just nullable references, and they get smart cast to their non-nullable types when you call them with `?.`.

Comment: Take a look at this document to see when you should you each of the scoping functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html

Comment: I wouldn't introduce such functions you have shown; not even if they would look as familiar as follows (basically mimicing Javas `Optional`): `fun <T> T?.ifPresent(block : T.() -> Unit) { this?.also(block) }`. Kotlin supports the concept of nullable and non-nullable types and if I need to use the former (rarely), then I want to see that it is an exception from the norm (`?.` or `?:` in place). Finally everyone familiar with Kotlin understands `let`, `also`, `apply`, `run`, `with` (sooner or later) and doesn't need to learn a new method that is basically just a rewrite of what's already there.